# Partitioning a matrix in 5 sets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, partitioning

I have a matrix

```
sV:=[0 -1; 
     1  1; 
     1  0;  
     2  1; 
     2  0; 
     3  1; 
     3  0]
```

Imagine that the matrix `sV` represents a set whose elements are the `1x2` row vectors listed above.

There are several ways in which we can partition the set `sV` in 5 non-empty set (140 from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)).

For example a way of 5-partitioning `sV` is:

```
{(0,-1)}
{(1,1)} 
{(1,0)}
{(2,1)}
{(2,0), (3,2), (3,0)}
```

The possible cardinalities of the partitioning sets are `1,1,1,1,3` or `1,1,1,2,2` (without considering the order).

**QUESTION:**

Could you help me to construct a `1x2` cell `V_all` such that

`V_all{1,1}` is an `mx5` cell listing all possible ways of 5-partitioning the set `sV` such that the partitioning sets have, respectively, cardinality `1,1,1,1,3`. Specifically, for any j=1,...,m, `V_all{1,1}{j,1}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,2}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,3}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,4}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,5}` should be a `3x2` vector.

`V_all{1,2}` is an `nx5` cell listing all possible ways of 5-partitioning the set `sV` such that the partitioning sets have, respectively, cardinality `1,1,1,2,2`. Specifically, for any j=1,...,n, `V_all{1,1}{j,1}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,2}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,3}` should be a `1x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,4}` should be a `2x2` vector, `V_all{1,1}{j,5}` should be a `2x2` vector.

Notice that `m+n=140`.

---

Here my attempt. There may be errors because I get more than 140 partitions.

```
%3+1+1+1+1
k=3;
M=reshape(sV(nchoosek(1:size(sV,1),k),:),[],k,size(sV,2));
V_1=cell(size(M,1),2); 
for p=1:size(M,1)
    V_1{p,1}=squeeze(M(p,:,:)); 
    left=~ismember(sV, V_1{p,1}, 'rows');
    V_1{p,2}=sV(left,:); 
end
%Rearrange
for j=1:size(V_1,1)
    V_1new{j,1}=V_1{j,1};
    V_1new{j,2}=V_1{j,2}(1,:);
    V_1new{j,3}=V_1{j,2}(2,:);
    V_1new{j,4}=V_1{j,2}(3,:);
    V_1new{j,5}=V_1{j,2}(4,:);
end
V_all{1,1}=V_1new;

%2+2+1+1+1
k=4;
M=reshape(sV(nchoosek(1:size(sV,1),k),:),[],k,size(sV,2));
V_2=cell(size(M,1),2); 
for p=1:size(M,1)
    V_2{p,1}=squeeze(M(p,:,:)); 
    left=~ismember(sV, V_2{p,1}, 'rows');
    V_2{p,2}=sV(left,:); 
end

k=2;
count=0;
for j=1:size(V_2,1)
    M=reshape(V_2{j,1}(nchoosek(1:size(V_2{j,1},1),k),:),[],k,size(V_2{j,1},2));
    V_2_22=cell(size(M,1),2); 
    for p=1:size(M,1)
        V_2_22{p,1}=squeeze(M(p,:,:)); 
        left=~ismember(V_2{j,1}, V_2_22{p,1}, 'rows');
        V_2_22{p,2}=V_2{j,1}(left,:); 
    end
    for l=1:size(V_2_22,1)
        V_2new{count+l,1}=V_2_22{l,1};
        V_2new{count+l,2}=V_2_22{l,2};
        V_2new{count+l,3}=V_2{j,2}(1,:);
        V_2new{count+l,4}=V_2{j,2}(2,:);
        V_2new{count+l,5}=V_2{j,2}(3,:);
    end
    count=size(V_2new,1);
end

V_all{1,2}=V_2new;
```

Comment: well. have you tried *anything*?

Comment: I have the code if I wanted 2 partitioning sets. Suppose that the 2 partitioning sets should have cardinalities 3,4 respectively. Then the code to create all possible partitions is ....

Comment: k=3;
M=reshape(sV(nchoosek(1:size(sV,1),k),:),[],k,size(sV,2));
V_34=cell(size(M,1),2); 
for p=1:size(M,1)
    V_34{p,1}=squeeze(M(p,:,:)); 
    left=~ismember(sV, V_34{p,1}, 'rows');
    V_34{p,2}=sV(left,:); 
end

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to nicely write a Matlab code in the comments

Comment: Edit your post and include your code in it!

Comment: Ok, done, I have included my attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find positions of partitioning we can use powerset
for example if an element of powerset is [2 3] the set will be partitoned this way:

```
0 -1; 
1  1; 
-----   <-- 2
1  0;
-----   <-- 3
2  1; 
2  0; 
3  1; 
3  0]
```

then we can get number of elements in each partition(num_el)  in this case : [2 , 1, 4]
this is the cardinality but because order of elements in cardinality is not importatnt so[ 2, 1, 4] is the same as [1 4 2] we can sort it to get [ 1 2 4]

then we need an associative container(dictionary) to map the cardinality to a set of partitions.

associative container in matlab can be implemented by struct so we need to change representation of cardinality form array of numbers to string so can be used as a key for struct then we get: '_1_2_4'

V_all is the associative container implemented as structure array:

V_all('_1_2_4') = { {}....}

```
sV=[0 -1; 
     1  1; 
     1  0;  
     2  1; 
     2  0; 
     3  1; 
     3  0]

n = size(sV,1)
p=powerset(1:(n-1));

cardinality =sprintf('_%i',n);
V_all.(cardinality)(end+1)={sV};
for i = 2:numel(p)
    num_el = [p{i} n] - [0 p{i}];
    cardinality = sprintf('_%i',sort(num_el));
    cum = [0 cumsum(num_el)];
    temp = {};
    for j = 2: numel(cum)
        temp(end + 1) = {sV(cum(j-1)+1:cum(j),:)};
    end
    V_all.(cardinality)(end+1)={temp};
end
```